# Which BDD framework for JavaScript do you use?

Tags: javascript, testing, extjs, bdd

I'm developing large application using ExtJS framework. Because it grows too fast, I realized that this might be the time to start doing tests.

I want to go for BDD technique, I found several BDD frameworks for JavaScript around (Screw.Unit, JSpec, JSSpec), but I'm still not sure which one to choose. There are some articles about this topic, but I'm more interested in your own experiences/suggestions.

So my questions are:

- Which one do you use and why?
- Any other hints/tips are welcome.
- Do you use Selenium alongside a BDD testing?
- Do you use any other technique?

Answer (score 1):

We use Selenium, yes.

I wrote a Unit Test framework (well, most of one, functional, not entirely pluggable) that I have used a few times. These sorts of topics keep coming up so maybe I should finish it... the url is http://code.google.com/p/jasproject/

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I use buster.js because I develop in node.js as well as client-side javascript. It copes with both scenarios using a single API. The documentation is still lacking, but I really like the support for asynchronous testing.

Buster can also be used in a similar way to Selenium's WebDriver - you can slave various browsers to a buster "server" and run your tests in all those browsers at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Functional web testing has several challenges. Tests tend to be...

1. Slow to run (http requests are slow, dom traversal can be slow too)
2. Slow to write (write a test, start the app, run the test, realise you made a mistake, start again)
3. Hard to read (xpaths, css selectors etc)
4. Brittle (when tightly coupled to your HTML)
5. Expensive to maintain (if you don't use an abstraction layer such as the page object pattern)
6. Unrealistic (when run in a fake browser)

For these reason my preferred stack is

1. JavaScript - development time is fast since there's no compilation time
2. CasperJS or Zombie JS - very fast, webkit based (Safari & Chrome [for now])
3. Yadda for **true** BDD - Makes the test easy to read and provides an abstraction layer, mitigating the brittleness and maintenance

Downsides of this stack is that you're only testing in webkit, not firefox, IE or Chrome (when Google move to Blink)